# How can I importing external JS file in Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am finding problem in adding the external js file to Ionic 3. Here is what I did, I have created a `hamburg.js` file in `src/js/hamburg.js`, and called the script file in index.html at `app/index.html`. And I have added the html code in `testpage.hmtl` and css in `testpage.scss`. Also declared in `app.component.ts`. Here is my code

app.component.ts
        declare var wrapperMenu;

hamburg.js

```
var wrapperMenu = document.querySelector('.wrapper-menu');

wrapperMenu.addEventListener('click', function(){


wrapperMenu.classList.toggle('open');
})
```

index.html

```
<script src="assets/js/hamburg.js"></script>
```

testpage.html

```
<div class="wrapper-menu">
<div class="line-menu half start"></div>
<div class="line-menu"></div>
<div class="line-menu half end"></div>
```

Can somebody guide me please?

Comment: Can you share the URL of your  JS library?

Comment: Hi Sampath, here is the link, which I wanted to integrate the same to Ionic 3 https://codepen.io/JoseRosario/pen/BWqMwK

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to external js file, this plugin play mostly with CSS.

this snippet

```
var wrapperMenu = document.querySelector('.wrapper-menu');
 wrapperMenu.addEventListener('click', function(){
 wrapperMenu.classList.toggle('open');  
})
```

can be putted on app.component.ts file. or if you have separate component for the header will be better to put the code in its ts file specifically on `ngOnInit()` hook.

**Edit** the best hook in component [life-cycle](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) is to put this code into `ngAfterViewInit()`  hook.

**Edit 2:** Another good practice is to used the predefined class `menu-content-open` that is added automatically when the menu is opened and you can change the selector in your CSS code from `.open` to `menu-content-open`

check my forked example from your original one [here](https://codepen.io/w34/pen/VMJRaR).
Note the code will work perfect when you add it into the ionic app.

Comment: Hi Peter, When I added the same in app.module.ts, it thrown an error like this TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
&nbsp;/build/main.js:1505:13 Object.243()
&nbsp;/build/vendor.js:55:30 __webpack_require__()
&nbsp;/build/main.js:1309:70 Object.224()
&nbsp;/build/vendor.js:55:30 __webpack_require__()
&nbsp;/build/vendor.js:26:23 webpackJsonpCallback()
&nbsp;/build/main.js:1:1

Comment: I am very sorry I meant app.component.ts, I edited my answer, here you can find a hook called ngOnInit to put your code inside

Comment: Could your provide a snippets of code from your ionic app itself.